# WSDL endpoint URL connection

Tags: soap, soapui, python-requests

I'M new to WSDL and SOAPUI.. I have a WSDL and need to make a connection to the endpoint and verify its working..

QUestion:-

```
1.Is it possible to make requests to the endpoint given in the WSDL  directly using Python requests or urllib modules?
2.If I have a WSDL, the only way to make connection to the webservice is using the WSDL?
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you can use any language to make a call to any web service - [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/) and Google is your friend.
2. [The Web Services Description Language is an XML-based interface definition language that is used for describing the functionality offered by a web service.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language) You do not "use the WSDL" to make a connection. You use the WSDL to figure out how to construct the message which you intent to send to the service.